# how to search all / wildcard in lucern solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, wildcard

I'm using RoR + acts_as_solr to query a Solr database.

I'm used to using "*" to select all, thanks to MySQL, but that command fires an exception in Solr. Are they other wildcards I can use? Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't query for "all" in lucene. The typical way to do it is to add a field with the same value for all documents and query for that value.

Comment: This is a wrong answer, see Mauricios answer below, i.e. use *:* in the query.

Answer (score 14):

In Solr you can get all documents by querying `*:*` (except for pagination, that's [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315434/how-to-get-all-docs-with-actsassolr/1316394#1316394))

Answer (score 2):

I prefer  [* TO *] when I have used acts_as_solr.  `*:*` seemed to perform much slower.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to select all data for. By emulating a select * I assume you want all fields back from the document; this would happen naturally from your search terms as you just limit the documents returned.

```
select * from index where id = 'Burrito'
```

would be the same as just searching for

```
id:Burrito
```

You would not have to do

```
*:* AND id:Burrito
```

If you want to see all the documents then use *:* as already suggested.