# how to get all docs with acts_as_solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lucene, solr

I'm doing something like this:

```
Item.find_by_solr('name:ab*')
```

and it says it returns 297 results:

```
=> #<ActsAsSolr::SearchResults:0xb6516858 @total_pages=1, @solr_data={:docs=>[doc1, doc2, doc3...]}, :max_score=>1.6935261, :total_pages=>1, :total=>297}, @current_page=1>

Item.count_by_solr('name:ab*') also returns 297.
```

Yet when iterate it only shows 10 items:

```
Item.find_by_solr('reference_name:ab*').each do |i| puts i end
```

I tried adding {:per_page=>80} and :limit=>:all but it still shows those 10. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Solr FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#head-ad538363dc33eba936af39b95ad0f0e719fa84d3):

> **How can I get ALL the matching
> documents back?** ... **How can I return
> an unlimited number of rows?**
>
> This is
> impractical in most cases. People
> typically only want to do this when
> they know they are dealing with an
> index whose size guarantees the result
> sets will be always be small enough
> that they can feasibly be transmitted
> in a manageable amount -- but if
> that's the case just specify what you
> consider a "manageable amount" as your
> rows param and get the best of both
> worlds (all the results when your
> assumption is right, and a sanity cap
> on the result size if it turns out
> your assumptions are wrong)

As for specifying a limit with `acts_as_solr`, try something like `:limit => 80`

Comment: Did you read my question? I said I already tried :limit and :per_page and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I did. You mentioned :per_page=>80 and :limit=>:all but not :limit =><number> Why should I assume that you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

as @mausch said Solr (and by extension `acts_as_solr`) defaults to 10 results. You can use the :limit option to increase this, but it only takes a Fixnum, not the :all symbol. So specify :limit with a Fixnum.

Answer (score 0):

I have in my sketchy notes that you can modify parser_methods.rb, around l. 75 to return only AR ID's, not the objects themselves.  Worth a try in large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the :offset parameter in your query.

So to the see the next 10 entries(11th to 20th) of Item you have to do this,

```
Item.find_by_solr('name:ab*', :offset => 10)
```

And to see the next 10 entries, you have to again increase the :offset parameter by 10. So the next 10 entries would look like this.

```
Item.find_by_solr('name:ab*', :offset => 20)
```

10 entries are fetched because the the default value of the :limit parameter is 10. We can change it to something else, if we want to fetch more than 10 entries at a time.

```
# This query fetches 30 items, offset by 30. (assuming more than 30 entries are found by this query)
Item.find_by_solr('name:ab*', :limit => 30, :offset => 30)
```