# Can I do Wildcard searches in Solr 1.3?

Tags: solr

Simple question, simple answer. Is it possible? If so, a link to where I can find out more about it?

I'm looking for doing a search such as "*apple" which would return stuff like "apple computer, big apple" etc.

Comment: In your example.. Just searching for "apple" will bring both results back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading wildcards (e.g. "*apple") are not yet supported in Solr. You can [vote/watch the issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-218).

[Other wildcard searches](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) work just fine.

Comment: Cool.. I didn't see the voting/watching sections.. very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to specify a field (or a wildcard field). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977560/how-to-search-all-wildcard-in-lucern-solr)